# scraping tables with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I seem to be stuck, If i had the following table:

```
<table align=center cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=1>
<tr bgcolor="#EEEEFF">
   <td align="center">
   40   </td>
   <td align="center">
   44   </td>
   <td align="center">
   <font color="green"><b>+4</b></font>
   </td>
   <td align="center">
   1,000</td>
   <td align="center">
   15,000   </td>
   <td align="center">
   44,000   </td>
   <td align="center">
   <font color="green"><b><nobr>+193.33%</nobr></b></font>
   </td>

</tr>
```

what would be the ideal way to use find_all to pull the 44,000 td from the table?

Comment: What distinguishes the `44,000` tablecell from the other cells? Why that specific value?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a recurring position of the table you would like to scrape you would like to scrape I would use beautiful soup to extract all elements in the table and then extract that data. See the pseudo code below.

```
known_position = 5
tds = bs4.find_all('td')
number = tds[known_position].text()
```

on the other hand if you're specifically searching for a given number I would just iterate over the list.

```
tds = bs4.find_all('td')
for td in tds:
    if td.text = 'number here':
        # do your stuff
```